# Understanding the judgment "$a\equiv b:A$" in homotopy type theory

Tags: logic, homotopy-type-theory

On page 31 of [*Homotopy Type Theory*](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) by the Univalent Foundations Program at the Institute for Advanced Study, the authors say that homotopy type theory is a deductive system based on two judgments: $a:A$ and $a\equiv b:A$.

I understand what these judgments mean when $A$ is a type, but if we consider $A$ to be a proposition, is the second judgement to say "defining $a$ as $b$ proves $A$" or am I misinterpreting the language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since propositions are just another variety of type, it means the same thing it does for any other kind of type. It means that $a$ and $b$ are the same proof of $A$; in HoTT even propositions can have many different proofs, even if all of these are propositionally equal (in the sense of there existing a term $p:a=_A b$). The $a\equiv b:A$ judgments say that $a$ and $b$ are equal in, roughly, the classical logician's much stricter sense of equality.

Hopefully this answers your question.